# javascript how to gather values from a html form

Tags: javascript, html

javascript how to gather values from a html form

```
    <html>
    <input id="numb"><br><br>
    <input id="numb2"><br><br>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    </html>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x, y, z;

    x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    y = document.getElementById("numb2").value;
    z = x + y;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
    }
    </script>
```

When i whrite in the first textbox number 2 and in the second number 3, it shoud display 5, but its displaying 23.
Can you help me? I want to display 5 from 2 + 3, not 23.

Comment: Use `Number()`. Also please make sure your HTML is valid…

Comment: Try `z = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value retrieve from control is a string .

If your value is int then parse it to int

```
z = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
```

If your value is float then parse it to float

```
z = parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y);
```

Comment: Damn, 4 seconds before me :p

Comment: @NewToJS That was close :P

Comment: pinch @Tom-OliverHeidel :P

Answer (score 0):

If the values are Strings you will get concatenation. So you can convert it to number with Number JavaScript object. Like Number(x).

For more information refer : 
[Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)